# node.js cannot send response within req.form.complete

Tags: node.js

In a node app I retrieve the content of a request with req.form.complete as follow (very simplified)

```
app.post('/myaction',  function(req, res){
    req.form.complete(function(err1, fields, files){
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        if (err1) {
            res.write("KO");
         } else {
            ... check something in db...
            res.write("ok");
         }
         res.end();    
      });
 });
```

My client never gets a response back. Seems to me the req.form.complete prevent the response from being sent... The idea behind this is to be able to parse the form and retrieve a picture  within that form and then perform additional checks in DB before sending a response back.

Any idea to perform this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in fact I have removed the BodyParser option and used connect-form, it's working fine like that. Still need to give formidable a shoot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest Express (which has Connect > 1.8.x), then it has req.files, which contains the files already parsed for you, try the following snippet:

```
app.post('/myaction',  function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.files));
});
```

Comment: does req.fields work also ? I had some problem last time knowing which one among connect-form and formidable was the best one.

Comment: @Luc they work if you have the latest Express version, see the official example here: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/examples/bodyParser.js#L22 . connect-form is deprecated now, and formidable is included directly into the bodyParser() from what I saw.